# iOS app crashes on Font when uploading to TestFlight but works fine when running on debug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using custom fonts in my application and it works just fine when I build and run on my device, but when I deploy it to Test Flight, it immediately crashes on launch.

This is the code I use for my fonts:

```
extension UIFont {

    public enum MSTFonts: String {

        case regular = "-Regular"

        case semibold = "-Semibold"

        case bold = "-Bold"

        case extraBold = "-ExtraBold"

        case black = "-Black"

    }

    static func proxima(_ type: MSTFonts = .regular, size: CGFloat = UIFont.systemFontSize) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: "ProximaNova\(type.rawValue)", size: size)!
    }

    var isBold: Bool {
        
        return fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
        
    }

    var isItalic: Bool {
        
        return fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic)
        
    }

}
```

and this is the crash log:

[image]

I have no idea what happened. I have added my font files to my target, info.plist and development assets.

Comment: Try deleting the app from your device and then doing a clean build. Does the app still run just fine from Xcode after that?

Comment: Yes it works fine the fonts work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the font file is included in the `Target Membership`?

[image]

Comment: Yes I have, in all of the fonts.

Comment: Since it only occurs on the TestFlight, there seems to be a difference between Debug mode and Release mode. Please upload information such as info.plist and project file.